# Using util-linux rename command

Tags: linux, command-line, rename

I've been attempting to use the util-linux version of rename (2011) to replace a specific string in all files with another. While I realize the perl version of rename would offer a solution, I can't figure out how to use this version of rename.

The specific example are a set of files (something--2013.mkv, somethingelse--2011.mkv), and I'm trying to remove the double dashes and replace with a space.

Comment: did you try something like this `rename 's/--/\ \ /' *.mp4`

Comment: rename 's///' is syntax for the perl version, not the util-linux version. If I were using the perl version, your command would work on .mp4 files :)

Comment: `--` means "the end of the options" for programs using `getopt` (such as `rename`). The solution is most likely to find the way around that. Perhaps you could translate `-` into something else first (e.g. `_`) and then replace that?

Comment: I have tried rename '--' ' ' *.mkv but this does not work.

Comment: Of course it doesn't: the shell interprets the quotes and the command just gets `--`

Comment: How should it be able to rename '--' to '_' if it cannot correctly interpret the variables?

Comment: Rename one dash (-) at first (e.g. to a single underscore _), then rename two (e.g. __) to a single dash. I can't test whether it works because I'm not on Linux right ATM. Otherwise I'd have posted as an answer. Another options could be to try `rename -- -- - file`

Comment: Renaming a single dash at a time to an underscore, then renaming the double underscore works. If you want to post an answer I can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `rename` uses `getopt` for argument parsing and thus has a special interpretation for double dash (`--`). `--` signifies the end of the arguments.

A solution would be to avoid using `--` in your command. One way to do this is to break your command into sub targets, e.g. translate single dash to underscore, then two underscores to single dash:

```
$ rename - _ *.mkv
$ rename __ - *.mkv
```

A less roundabout way to do this is to actually use the `getopt` behavior

```
$ rename -- -- - *.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

The rename from util-linux is in `/usr/bin/rename.ul` in Ubuntu. So you could use the `rename.ul` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir TEMP
numbers=2011
find . -name "*.mkv" | while read filename
do
  echo mv "$filename" "TEMP/somethingelse_"$((numbers++)).mkv
  rm filename
done
```

Comment: this script does not utilize the util-linux version of rename.